# using multiple and or statements in if condition

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


main()
{
  char a[2];



  cout << "         \"Welcome to Virtual University\" " << endl;
  cout << "     Program to predict user programming level" << endl;

  cout << " Please answer in either T=True or F=False" << endl;

  cout << "Q:1 Switch is a loop?" << endl;
  cout << "A:  ";
  cin >> a[0];

cout << "Q:2 Pointer stores memory address?" << endl;
cout << "A:  ";
cin >> a[1];

cout << "Q:3 Semicolon after for loop is an error? " << endl;
cout << "A:  ";
cin >> a[2];



if((a[0] == 'f') || (a[0] == 'F') && (a[1] == 't') || (a[1] == 'T') && (a[2] 
== 'f') || (a[2] == 'F')) 
    {
        cout << "Your programming level is advanced" << endl;
    }
 else if((a[0] == 'f') || (a[0] == 'F') && (a[1] == 't' ) || (a[1] == 'T') 
&& (a[2]== 't') || (a[2] == 'T')) 
    {
        cout << "Your programming level is intermediate" << endl;
    }
else if((a[0] != 'f') || (a[0] != 't') && (a[1] != 't' ) || (a[1] != 'f') && 
(a[2] != 't') || (a[2] != 'f')) 
    {
        cout << "please enter t or f only" << endl;
    }
else
    {
        cout << "Your programing level is begginner" << endl;
    }
    return 0;



}
```

its not giving any errors in compiler but when i run this`` program it always prints the wrong statement. can you guyz please help me.
and when i remove the || conditions with capital  F and T. its working fine.
can any one help putting those capital letters as well because its a requirement in my assignment. thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Did you know that the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `||` operator?  In your `if` conditions, you probably want to add extra parentheses so that the `||` operations are blocked together.

Comment: if(((a[0] == 'f') || (a[0] == 'F')) && ((a[1] == 't') || (a[1] == 'T')) && ((a[2] == 'f') || (a[2] == 'F'))) 
  {
   cout << "Your programming level is advanced" << endl;
  }
 else if(((a[0] == 'f') || (a[0] == 'F')) && ((a[1] == 't') || (a[1] == 'T')) && ((a[2] == 'f') || (a[2] == 'F'))) 
  {
   cout << "Your programming level is intermediate" << endl;
  }
 else if(((a[0] != 'f') || (a[0] != 't')) && ((a[1] != 't' ) || (a[1] != 'f'))&& ((a[2] != 't') || (a[2] != 'f'))).....do you mean this? its also not working bro .